# Android: how can i display chronometer from another layout in dialog

Tags: java, android, layout, timer, chronometer

```
chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
```

> how can i display chronometer from another layout in dialog?

```
public class StopDialog extends DialogFragment{
     public static Button bt;
     public static View stopdialogView;
     public static  Chronometer ch;
    public static  Chronometer ch1;
        public StopDialog(){}
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            stopdialogView = View.inflate( getActivity(), R.layout.stopdialog, null );
            bt= stopdialogView.findViewById( R.id.button );
            //
            //
            //
```

> i want to replace this chronometer to another chronometer?
>    I tried getText, getFormat, getBase, etc, but none of them could work.

```
            //
            //
            ch = (Chronometer) stopdialogView.findViewById( R.id.stoptimer);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){

                    if (MainActivity.p==3){
                        click1();
                    }else{
                        click2();
                    }
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
        return stopdialogView;
        }
    public void click1(){
            //MainActivity.chronometer.setBase( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            MainActivity.chronometer.stop();
        }
        public void click2(){

            //MainActivity.chronometer1.setBase( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            MainActivity.chronometer1.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What is `activity_main.xml`? Please read [ask] and [mcve] for tips to improve your question so that we can help you.

Comment: its activity_main.xml where this chronometer is i have big code so i cant post it fully.
i want to display chronometers count in dialog, or access its value.

Comment: Thanks for posting some of your code. To clarify, I did not ask you to post all of your code. I gave a link that explains how to create a **minimal** example while still being **complete**. Please take some time to read the links I gave and continue to edit your question to improve is so that we can give you the answers you need.

Comment: ok thank you for advice